# TypeGraphQL_How to avoid creating fields that have not been inputted

Tags: typescript, mongodb, graphql, resolver, typegraphql

```
@Resolver()
export class NameCardCreateResolver {
  @Mutation(() => BaseMutationResponse)
  async namecardCreate(
    @Arg("chosenSNSUrls", () => SNSInput)
    { facebook, twitter, instagram, blog, youtube }: SNSInput,
    @Arg("owner", () => NameCardOwner)
    { ownerEmail }: NameCardOwner
  ): Promise<BaseMutationResponse> {
    const response = new BaseMutationResponse();
    try {
      await NameCardModel.create({
        sns: {
          facebook,
          twitter,
          instagram,
          blog,
          youtube
        },
        owner: {
          email: ownerEmail,
        },
```

and also SNSINPUT type ,,

```
@InputType()
export class SNSInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  facebook?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  instagram?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  youtube?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  blog?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true, defaultValue: null })
  twitter?: string;
}
```

it works well,, but it's created like this in my field in MongoDB.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vW3m.png)

How can I prevent unnecessary null processed sns field from being created?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to save a field to MongoDB set its value to `undefined` (instead of `null`). This should omit the field entirely from the document.

You may have to remove the `defaultValue: null` from your typegraphql annotation since this probably sets it to `null` by default.

```
@InputType()
export class SNSInput {
  @Field({ nullable: true })
  facebook?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  instagram?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  youtube?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  blog?: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  twitter?: string;
}
```

Or, if you want to preserve the `null` values on your input, you'll either have to explicitly override them with `undefined` or remove them entirely using `delete`.